# Android SQLite Display all records in Listview

Tags: sqlite, loops, listview

I have been on this all weekend and Im at my wits end as to how to return all records in a query into a listview

the following code works perfectly

```
public void DisplayContact(String sitename)
{
final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();  

Cursor c = db.getAsset6(sitename);
int mx=0;
String[] lvdata = new String[c.getCount()-1];
while (c.moveToNext()) {
lvdata[mx]=c.getString(2) + "-" + c.getString(1) + "-" + c.getString(6);
mx++;

}
getActionBar().setTitle("Number of Records = " + mx); 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, lvdata);
setListAdapter(adapter);

}

public Cursor getAsset6(String strname) throws SQLException 
{ 
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
                     new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_FAULTREF,KEY_WORKNUM,KEY_ORIGNUM,KEY_REPBY,KEY_REPDATTIM,KEY_DESCRIPTION},
                     KEY_REPBY + " LIKE ?",
                     new String[] { "%" + strname + "%" },
                     null, null, null, null); if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;                           
}
```

The problem is it doesnt add the first item in the query (ie there are 151 records in the query but it only puts 150 in the listview missing the first entry)

I am sure its something to do with c.moveToFirst(); and a Do Statement but i have read every article I can find on here and whatever combination I try it crashes when I run the query in the app. I am running the app using an external database so I cant see whats causing the crash in eclipse

Can one of you SQL gurus help me out its driving me crazy

Your help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution is to remove this line from from your getAsset6() method:

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
```

What is happening, is that the cursor is being created and you are then setting it to the first row of the results set. Your while loop is then defined as:

```
while (c.moveToNext())
```

The condition of a while loop is evaluated first to determine whether the code that follows should run. So this statement advances your cursor to the second row before you beginning adding to your lvdata[] array. Hence the first row is getting skipped. By removing the moveToFirst(), your code should still work. The moveToNext() in the while loop will set the cursor to the first row in its first iteration and you'll get all your data into the array. If your cursor happens to be empty, moveToNext() will return false and nothing will get added to the array.

Comment: Hi Nigel Unfourtunately if I remove the line the app crashes if the line is left in it works fine except for not showing the first record. I just dont know where im going wrong

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting in your logcat output to your question?

Comment: sorry Nigel I wish I knew how to do that. the app is running on my device as it uses a database on the sd card do you know any good tutorials on how to do it?

Comment: OK Nigel I learnt how to connect my phone using eclipse the error it crashes on when I remove the line is  "ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: Lenght=54; index=54; in Activity 3. Activity 3 is where the main code is not Asset6 which is in the db helper

Comment: You define lvdata[] as having c.getCount()-1 elements. Try dropping the -1. Now that you're getting all the rows, I think your array is 1 element too small.